# Is this circuit safe?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, led-strip, pir

What the circuit does is very simple: once the PIR motion sensor detects a motion, the OUT pin is high (3.3v) and it will put the MOSFET in an open state. The LED strip will be therefore on.

It's working like a charm but I think I'm missing some components to make a more robust circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz8PvY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some information about the voltage source: it's a 220v AC to 12v (adjustable) DC converter. It seems that the LED strip is slightly blinking from time to time. I don't know if it's because of the converter or the MOSFET.

Any help for a newbie will be appreciated.

Comment: A note on style: Your schematic is upside down! It's customary to put ground at the bottom.

Comment: @duskwuff: It's customary to put *negative* at the bottom. GND can be on the supply positive.

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me. You might put 100Ω between M1 gate and OUT for complicated but possibly unnecessary reasons. Check your connections re: blinking

Comment: Generally, though, open-ended questions like this are somewhat frowned upon for SE. You might get some downvotes, just a heads up.

Comment: A pointer to the specific PIR sensor might give us more to check

Comment: @Daniel or is that a heads down in this instance ;)

Comment: Another note: "open" usually means "off" - an "open circuit" is a circuit in which current does not flow. An open switch is a switch in the off position - so a MOSFET in the open state is .... ?

Comment: No, the battery is upside down. The acid will leak out!

Comment: I would decrease G-S resistor value to somewhat 10k-47k value. 1Mohm is too high for a transistor like this.

Comment: Sorry for the very bad schematic :)
@Daniel There you go, -1 ahaha You were right. Although I know it's kinda an open-ended question, I just expected answers like 'yes' or 'no because'.

Comment: I expect an open collector pull-down output as a first approximation, you would want to add a pull-up resistor for reliable operation.  The make and model of the PIR sensor would assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMNemX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Circuit redrawn "right-way up".*

The circuit looks fine although, as pointed out in the comments, you might add a resistor between the out pin and the gate. The gate has some capacitance and the resistor prevents it acting as an instantaneous short when OUT changes state.

Note the schematic convention is highest voltages at the top and lowest at the bottom. Signal flow is generally from left to right as with western writing. (This doesn't always work out and the power in this case flows from right to left to keep the schematic "clean".)

Some older transistor circuits in particular used a common positive. In those circuits GND appeared at the top of the schematic.

Note also how easy it is to identify the ground points, without having to trace wires, when the symbols are used.

Comment: +1 for redraw. Depending on how that is wired up, some decoupling / bulk caps on the sensor may be prudent too.

Answer (score 1):

You *ought* to be OK. But be aware that your gate drive is marginal. If you look at the [data sheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz34n.pdf) you'll see that the gate threshold voltage is 1 to 2 volts. Since this provides a drain current of 250 uA, a 50% margin for a 1 amp current is not healthy. A good rule of thumb is 3 times Vgs(th). I'd recommend a level shifter like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGB5Ig.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

should give adequate margin.